# Is it possible to disable lazy class loading for a Rails console run in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When running Rails console in development mode, Rails will lazy load all of the classes. This can be seen when running:

```
[2] pry(main)> ApplicationController.descendants
=> []
```

Is it possible to disable the lazy loading of controllers in development mode?

Comment: Lazy loading makes class aliasing useless. I, too, could use a pry or irb command to disable the lazy approach.

Answer (score 1):

In `config/environments/development.rb`, my application had

```
  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false
```

Changing that to `true` fixed it for me.